# Reading minidumps on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bsod, minidumps

Since last week I get a bluescreen everyday on my netbook which runs under Windows 8.
However, I don't know what causes the problem.
Because of this I want to read the created minidumps.
I tried to open and read these .dmp files with this program [Debuggers (x64)](http://www.windbg.org/).

When I try to open a crash dump it says that I don't have the required permission to open it.
Actually I am using an admin account on this machine and I gave me full access to this files in the advanced properties.

Does anyone have any idea how I can open these files without installing the windows debugging tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard tools for identifying a BSOD works fine in my experience - you may need to run as admin, but I've tried [bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) after inducing a BSOD intentionally and it works fine.

Windows 8 admin accounts arn't really admin - they only elevate you as needed, through runas or UAC

Comment: Hi, I've tryed to run the program as admin but the program isn't able to open the files as an admin. I used bluescreenview and it works for me now.  
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must run [WinDbg with admin rights](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) to open the dump when you don't have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I used this free web service:
http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze

Copy-paste `%windir%\Minidump` into the Windows Explorer's address line, order files by date, copy the most recent one, paste into some normal folder where your account has permissions (e.g. desktop or documents), sent to compressed (zipped) folder, then upload.

P.S. If it says ATTEMPTED_EXECUTE_OF_NOEXECUTE_MEMORY, PROCESS_NAME: MsMpEng.exe, and IMAGE_NAME: ndis.sys - I'm affected as well..